Second-order transitions as emergence of a third phase with conformal symmetry
During a transition we are passing from a phase to another one. What happens in between could be:

phase co-existence of the phase before + the phase after

conformal symmetry emergence, scale in variance, correlation length $\to \infty$


Now, the question seems tricky but the definition of phase is somewhat clear: different phases have different simmetries.
The definition of phase transition is clear too: non analicity in free energy. Thus we can transition from a phase to itself without any issue and that happens a lot.
Now: during a second order transition, for a certain set of couplings (or temperatures), conformal simmetry and scale invariance appear.
Isn't it just equivalent to say that another phase has emerged?
